# Express Jest and Supertest how to mock middleware with argument

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, mocking, supertest

I have been trying for several hours to test an endpoint of my rest api with Jest, Supertest and Express.

This endpoint is protected by an authentication middleware named "`advancedAuthGuard`".

**So I'm trying to mock this middleware in order to skip authentication check for endpoints testing**

```js
//./router.js 
router.get('/route1', advancedAuthGuard(false), controller);
```

Important: `advancedAuthGuard` is a **middleware that accepts configuration argument** ( curried middleware )

```js
//./middleware/advancedAuthGuard.js
const advancedAuthGuard = (additionalCondition) => (req,res,next) => {

  //Check authentication logic ...
  const isAuth = true

  if (isAuth && !additionalCondition)
    next()
  else
    next(new Error('Please auth'))
}
```

When I run the following test to check if I get status code '200' . The test fail before run.

```js
//./test.js
import supertest from "supertest"
import app from './app.js'
import { advancedAuthGuard } from "./middlewares/advancedAuthGuard";

jest.mock("./middlewares/advancedAuthGuard")

const request = supertest(app)

beforeEach(()=>{
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})

it("should '/route1' respond with 200 status", async ()=>{
  const mockedMiddleware = jest.fn().mockImplementation((res, req, next)=> next() )
  advancedAuthGuard.mockReturnValue(mockedMiddleware)
  const res = await request.get("/route1")
  expect(res.status).toEqual(200)
})
```

I get the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run
Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]


> 10 | router.get('/route1', advancedAuthGuard(false), controller);
     |        ^
```

**I therefore deduce that the problem comes from the mock...**

And when I debug it via console.log, I realize that I get an incomplete mock :

- I was able to verify that the mock of function (`advancedAuthGuard(false)`) was present
- But this mock should return a second mock of type `function (req,res,next){}`, however it only returns **undefined**

I also noticed that:

- This mock issue only occurs with curried middlewares (middleware with input parameters)
- This mock issue only occurs when the curried middleware is executed in express router. (When I tried the mock outside express router, the mock appears correctly)

**So I would like to know why it is impossible for me to mock a curried middleware** ( middleware with argument ) used in an Expressjs endpoint with Jest and Supertest.

Here is a github link with minimal express, jest, supertest config, where you can reproduce this problem, by running the `test.js` file. https://github.com/enzo-cora/jest-mock-middleware

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why it is not working the way you tried but if you pass the mock implementation to the autoMock function it will do the trick.

```js
import supertest from "supertest";
import app from "./app";


jest.mock("./middlewares/simpleAuthGuard", () => ({
  simpleAuthGuard: (_, __, next) => next()
}));
jest.mock("./middlewares/advancedAuthGuard", () => ({
  advancedAuthGuard: () => (_, __, next) => next()
}));

const request = supertest(app);

describe('My tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => jest.clearAllMocks());

  it("should '/route1' with advanced middleware work", async () => {
    const res = await request.get("/route1");
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
  });

  it("should '/route2' with simple middleware work", async () => {
    const res = await request.get("/route2")
    expect(res.status).toEqual(200)
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this allows at least to validate the test. BUT: 

However, I need to be able to control the implementation of my `advancedAuthGuard` through my various tests. (Sometime, i want send auth success, and other time I want send auth fail )

In your solution, the `advancedAuthGuard` works the same for all tests. So I could not create different authentication result scenarios in my test suit.